# Eclipse with ADT wont generate debug.keystore

Tags: android, eclipse

I have Eclipse Helios service release 2 with the ADT plugin. I need a debug.keystore for something but it refuses to generate it. I have added a sample Android project and built it without erros, and expects to see the file under C:\users\name\.android (which it says under Preferences-Android-Build) but it is not there. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

chech the path of keystroke eclipse->window->preferences->Android->Build

and you will see your path on right side.

Otherwise you can generate the keystroke using eclipse

right click on project and Android tools and then export signed Aplication.

hope it will help.

Comment: hm well i had the right path but somehow Eclipse didnt auto-generate it. however using "export signed..." worked